# How to find the top 5 values of a column according to another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am practising on the IMDB dataset and i would like to find the top genres that had the most budget.

Actually that would be useful in situations where a boxplot is needed and the genres are numerous. Thus, minimising them to the most expensive would make the boxplot more clear.

```
i tried this: df.sort_values(by=["genres","budget"])
```

but it isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need return all columns:

I think you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df=df.sort_values(by=["genres","budget"], ascending=[True, False]).groupby("genres").head(5)
```

Or [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
df = df.groupby('genres', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5, "budget"))
```

---

If need retun only `genres` and `budget` columns:

```
df = df.groupby('genres')["budget"].nlargest(2).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Samples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'budget':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'genres':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  E  budget genres
0  a  4  7  5       1      a
1  b  5  8  3       3      a
2  c  4  9  6       5      a
3  d  5  4  9       7      b
4  e  5  2  2       1      b
5  f  4  3  4       0      b
```

---

```
df1=df.sort_values(by=["genres","budget"], ascending=[True, False]).groupby("genres").head(2)

df1 = df.groupby('genres', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, "budget"))

print (df1)
   A  B  C  E  budget genres
2  c  4  9  6       5      a
1  b  5  8  3       3      a
3  d  5  4  9       7      b
4  e  5  2  2       1      b
```

---

```
df1=df.groupby('genres')["budget"].nlargest(2).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df1)
  genres  budget
0      a       5
1      a       3
2      b       7
3      b       1
```

### ---

If need top genres with sum of badget per genres:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'budget':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'genres':list('aabbcc')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  E  budget genres
0  a  4  7  5       1      a
1  b  5  8  3       3      a
2  c  4  9  6       5      b
3  d  5  4  9       7      b
4  e  5  2  2       1      c
5  f  4  3  4       0      c

df = df.groupby('genres')['budget'].sum().nlargest(2)
print (df)
genres
b    12
a     4
Name: budget, dtype: int64
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('genres')['budget'].sum())
genres
a     4
b    12
c     1
Name: budget, dtype: int64
```

Comment: In order to exclude the genres and put it in a boxplot: df.boxplot(column="budget",by=df['genres'] == "what do i put????????")

Comment: Do you want filter only one or multiple `genres`?

Comment: Because need 2 line code - first filter `df = df[df['genres'].isin(['a','b'])]` and then plot `df.boxplot(column="budget",by='genres')`

Comment: Actually i would like to include the 5 genres with the most budget.

Comment: Do you think last solution? Aggregate and filter top5 genres?

Comment: Then use `top5 = df.groupby('genres')['budget'].sum().nlargest(5).index` 
`df = df[df['genres'].isin(top5)]`, 
`df.boxplot(column="budget",by='genres')`

Comment: And one last thing, how to utilize sort_values in the last part of your answer called "detailed", in order to show according to numbers and not a b c but   b a c the genres

Comment: Then need add `.sort_index()`